# How to make <p> tag into parent of another <p> tag in jsx?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have this problem in which I'm trying to place the bottom p-tag positioned relative to the center of the top p-tag. If I were to use a relative position and use calc to 50% it will center this bottom p-tag relative to its parent element. How could I go about making the second child p-tag relative to only the above child p-tag to center it and stick it right below its top sibling?

this is an example of what I'm trying to do.

```css
#parent{
  display: inline-block;
  width: fit-content;
}
#child-1{
  background: blue;
}
#child-2{
  background: red;
  width: fit-content;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id = "parent">
    <p id = "child-1"> Child to be made into parent </p>
    <p id = "child-2"> centered sibling </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be use flexbox, like so. This is not relative to the first `p` tag, but with respect to the parent itself. But it gives an appearance that it's at the center.

```css
#parent {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#parent p {
  margin: 0;
}

#child-1 {
  background: blue;
}

#child-2 {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="parent">
    <p id="child-1"> Child to be made into parent </p>
    <p id="child-2"> centered sibling </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How would you approach having the bottom p-tag stick to the top one?

Comment: By stick, you mean no margin/padding around?

Comment: Yes, just set it all to 0?

Comment: Yes, just changed it in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this without flexbox. As you can see you were almost good. By using `width:fit-content` you are simply looking for `inline-block`.

```css
#parent {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

#parent>p {
 margin:0;
}

#child-1 {
  background: blue;
}

#child-2 {
  background: red;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="parent">
    <p id="child-1"> Child to be made into parent </p>
    <p id="child-2"> centered sibling </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```